# How to update opendata(Json file) to mongoDB periodically

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a new guys to mongoDB, Hope someone can hint me how to do this task.

I have a opendata URL:

http://data.taipei/opendata/datalist/apiAccess?scope=resourceAquire&rid=9ba187c9-b07e-40bc-9aa5-8d3c9f1aad63

Q1: For some reason, this Opendata doesn't contain the timeframe for data, so before I save and import the json file to mongodb, I would like to add current timeframe into it, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Q2: The opendata will get updated every 5 mins, and I would like to sync this to mongodb per 5 mins.(do merge but not overwrite, and not merge when records is same).
My idea is to use crontab to execute a script per 5 mins, but I am not sure if the scripts should use mongoImport or not, because it seem mongoImport will overwrite the entire DB files, where I want a merge instead of overwrite. So any suggestion to doing this task?

PS: Finally I might use R to analysis the data, but this is another story, the first task I need to do is to import the data periodically. Hope someone can give me some directions.

Thanks for your help!

Best Regards
james

Comment: StackOverflow tip. If when writing your question you start breaking things up into "Q1" and "Q2" etc, then you probably should be posting two or more questions. Tip2: (irony) Is that unless you can form a specific problem to be solved in a clear and definitive way, then each of those questions is in itself too broad a question for posting here. More information at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the data, but my advice is to parse the json file and then update or create existing fields, and add an "updated_at" field. Here is the pseudo code:

```
for each elem in json["results"] do

     existing = Data.where(:id=>elem["id"]).first  # find if there is already a field for this id

     if existing==null then   # if no create it
         existing = Data.new(:id=>elem["id"])
     end
     existing.update(elem)    # update all json data, depending of your language
     existing.updated_at=Time.now
     existing.save
end
```

mongoImport is only used to export/import data to backup/restore database, or some other very specific use case, but not in a normal operating process